# Echo inside a php code

Tags: php, wordpress, echo

I have a wordpress site and I get an error in the following code.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/<?php $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Monthly Fee', true); if ($url) { echo "rent2?domain=<?php the_title(); ?>&monthlyfee=$url";} else echo "rent?domain=<?php the_title(); ?>&monthlyfee=$url";?>">
```

the following command does not work in echo command. the result is text only.

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Comment: Why are you still including `$url` in your `else` block?

Comment: Your code is malformed. Please fix it first (so that all PHP code is contained inside `<?php ?>` tags, etc).

Comment: And so that there aren't nested `<?php ?>` tags...

Comment: The answer below is good, but I'll point out again here that `the_title()` function by default echoes by itself, that's why you can't use it inside an `echo` statement. Use `get_the_title()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer but an advice based on 19 years of experience.

Your problem is much bigger - messy code:

Don't try to cram all your logic in one line. Make your code readable. You will thank yourself later. Use proper variable names.

```
<?php
    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Monthly Fee', true);
    if ($post_meta) {
        $url = "rent2?domain=" . the_title() . "&monthlyfee=$post_meta";
    } else {
        $url = "rent?domain=" . the_title() . "&monthlyfee=$post_meta";
    }
?>

<a href="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $url; ?>">
```

The code above is (supposed to be) functionally identical to yours. But you can see that some things are written twice `?domain=" . the_title() . "&monthlyfee=$post_meta` and that in the `else` block `$post_meta` (formerly $url) is used while `$post_meta` is `falsy`. Is it intended? If then the only thing that is different is `rent` vs `rent2`. Your code can be made [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) like this:

```
<?php
    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Monthly Fee', true);
    $search_string = "?domain=" . the_title() . "&monthlyfee=$post_meta";
    $path = $post_meta ? "rent2" : "rent";
    $url = $path . $search_string;
?>
```

PS. As Dre pointed out `the_title()` should not do any `echo` but return title string! Thank you

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $url; ?>">
```

Comment: I understand that you're highlighting numerous errors in his code by refactoring to be more readable, you may want to consider adding a further example of how he could fix said problems. This would counteract any tendency on the OP's part of simply copying and pasting your code and finding it still doesn't work.
UPDATE: I see you did that just as I hit the 'send comment' button!

Comment: By default `the_title()` echos out the title, so can't be used to build a string like that; you either want to use `get_the_title()` or `the_title('','',FALSE)`, the third parameter being the boolean for whether to echo the title or just return it. Otherwise, good informative answer.

Comment: And once he sees that it still does not work he will hopefully looks at the code and finds the errors himself.

Comment: I must admit that i dislike using php files as templates. in other words in my current application of 1000+ php files, there is only ONE file that with ONE `echo` in it

Comment: At the risk of derailing the answer completely, what methodology are you using for front end templates? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Front end templates? You can do a lot of different things. straight forward HTML generation with string concatenations - not as readable as `blade` but still better that all those endless `<?php echo `s and `; ?>`s. Like i have multiline strings with variables inserted like this `{$variable_name}`. Those strings are returned. This is almost like templating. PHP templating engines (Smarty, Twig etc) is the step forward. Since recently a lot of client side rendering (JS) so that i only sent JSON to the clients. And now i am working on using Angular JS. This is the future, no doubt about it

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I've played around with Smarty, so I'll give it another look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66846/discussion-between-konstantin-and-dre).

Answer (score -1):

hon2a Already gave the answer in the comment. Your code is malformed. Because the part

```
echo "...<?php the_title(); ?>..."
```

is placed in a string, the_title is not interpreted as a function.

Comment: That's not the only problem. That's one of at least 3 glaring issues.